# Redirect http to https with nginx and rewrite a rule gives redirect loop

Tags: https, virtualhost, nginx

I want to redirect http to https along with

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
```

My nginx virtualhost file:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    domain.com;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen         443 ssl;
   server_name    domain.com;
   root /var/nginx/html;

   ssl_certificate /home/domain.crt
   ssl_certificate_key /home/domain.key

   location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm$
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

}
```

…but this gives me a redirect loop. Can somebody point me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

What happens if `/$1.php` does not exist either? I'm no expert on Nginx unfortunately, but on Apache this sort of rewrite could result in a rewrite loop (you would need to check that the file exists first before rewriting to it).

Should this not be rewritten using `try_files` only...? For example:

```
try_files $uri $url.php $uri/ /index.html;
```

Comment: No, nginx says Not found when such file is not present on server.

Comment: try_files $uri $url.php $uri/ /index.html;
Thanks this did the job!